# Understanding Before and After Attribute of Custom Element of Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am having difficulty in understanding the concept of **Custom** Element of Wix. I read [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/custom.html) and it says it is **Used to sequence a custom action**.

Now if you consider the follwing piece of Wix code:

```
<Binary Id="SetupCA"  SourceFile="..\..\ext_library\SetupCA\SetupCA\bin\Release\SetupCA.CA.dll"/>
<CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Sequence="2"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I want the Custom Action **WRITEFILETODISK** execute just before the MSI installs the file in my system. Even though I used **Sequence=2**, this is a bad way. So I must be using **Before** or **After** Attribute present in **Custom** tag. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) website gives info on InstallExecuteSequence, but it is vague for newbie like me. Most developers uses ***CostInitialize***, ***CostFinalize***, ***InstallInitialize***, ***InstallFinalize***. So I want to know the difference between the above attributes and when to use them properly while making MSI Installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too bad for the Install Execute stage:

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/standard-actions.html

This:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/21/how-windows-installer-engine-installs-the-installation-package.aspx

A typical order:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372038(v=vs.85).aspx

but you could always get Orca from the Windows Kit and look at the install sequences in the MSI file to see what specific order they have in your MSI files.

The big wrinkle is that the execute sequence has two phases that correspond to immediate ccustom actions (when nothing happens to the system) and deferred, when the changes actually happen. So to do something immediately before files are written to disk you'd have a deferred CA before InstallFiles.

Comment: Does any sequence number I gave in Custom tag works? Even the value I gave is 2, how's this working?

Comment: Your Comment helped me to understand it. Also I referred ***WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML***, which is also very good for newbie like me.